Why would the "helm template" command ignore values set on the command line?
I'm writing a Helm chart with a default value of true for a boolean flag in the Values.yaml file, and I want to test the results whenever that flag is set to false.
To be clear, the directory structure of the project looks like:
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── README.md
└── charts
    └── a
        ├── Chart.yaml
        ├── templates
        │   ├── _helpers.tpl
        │   ├── b
        │   │   └── deployment.yaml
        │   └── namespace.yaml
        └── values.yaml

The template yaml would look something like this, more or less:
{{- if (eq (toString .Values.mything.enabled) "true") }} 
          image: "foo/trueimage"
{{- else }}
          image: "foo/fakeimage"
{{- end }}    

And my Values.yaml file contains something like this, effectively:
mything:
   enabled: true

But the following command does not produce the expected YAML:
helm template . --set mything.enabled=false --debug > output.yaml

I've tried 0, "false", and "" in place of false in the command line. No luck.
The template command just seems to be ignoring everything after --set.
What am I missing here? Is the directory structure to blame? Wouldn't the command line --set values override the contents of the values.yaml file by default?

There's no need to convert mything.enabled to a string in the if condition.
Instead of:
{{- if (eq (toString .Values.mything.enabled) "true") }}

Try:
{{- if .Values.mything.enabled }}

Example
Values.yaml:
mything:
   enabled: true

templates/test.yaml:
{{- if .Values.mything.enabled }}
enabled: yes
{{- else }}
enabled: no
{{- end }}

Running helm template --set mything.enabled=false .:
---
# Source: example/templates/test.yaml
enabled: no

Running helm template --set mything.enabled=true .:
---
# Source: example/templates/test.yaml
enabled: yes

PS: I ran the above example using Helm v3.14.3.

Ah, I found some of the problem, which a misunderstanding of Helm charts and their propagation of values.
Helm charts should be designed to be standalone, so as a rule they don't automatically forward values to their subcharts. At the very least, the values.yaml file of the parent must have something like:
subchart:
  itemToChange: newValue

Alternatively, the top-most values.yaml file can have a global section:
global:
  itemToChange: newValue

..and every chart that needs the new value must refer to .Values.global.itemToChange in their templates.
These stipulations do exist in the Helm docs, but they're sort of buried in a subsection that can be easy to miss.
